# Typeface of Title and Buttons in a AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, typeface

I wonder if it's possible to set typeface of title and buttons in a AlertDialog?

Comment: Try [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Comment: with [StyleSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html)

Comment: or maybe [TypefaceSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.html)